# Finding the characteristic polynomial in quotient space.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$T:V\to V$ is a linear map on n-dimensional vector space. Suppose $c(x)=(x-d_1)^{e_1}...(x-d_k)^{e_k}$ be its characteristic polynomial where $e_1+e_2+...+e_k=n$. Let $V_1$ be the 1-dimensional subspace generated by an eigenvector corresponding to $d_1$. We consider the natural linear map $T':V/V_1 \to V/V_1$ due to $T$. I am trying to figure out the characteristic polynomial $c'(x)$ for $T'$.
I can see that each $d_i$ ,except possibily $d_1$ , will be the root of $c'(x)$ but cannot find its multiplicity. Also the degree of $c'(x)$ will be $n-1$.

Comment: We will simply have 
$$
c'(x) = \frac {1}{x - d_1} c(x)
$$
it is difficult to show this without one of the "powerful" results of linear algebra.  Do you know anything about upper-triangualrizing transformations?  Something about Jordan form, perhaps?

Comment: Well this is the result they have used in proof of upper triangularization which I am stuck at.

Comment: Have they established any properties of the determinant yet?  Do they define the characteristic polynomial in terms of the determinant?

Comment: yes I am familiar with basic results except canonical forms.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean by $V = V/V_1 \oplus V_1$?  Or $\det(T_1 \oplus T_2) = \det(T_1) \det(T_2)$?

Comment: yes, I am familiar with all these!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ where $v_1$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $d_1$.  The matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal B$ has the form
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{d_1 & c^T\\&A}
$$
where $A$ is an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix.  We then note that
$$
\det(xI - T) = \pmatrix{x - d_1 & c^T\\& xI - A} = (x-d_1)\det(x I - A)
$$
However, note that $A$ is the matrix of the natural linear map $T'$ with respect to the basis $\{v_2,\dots,v_n\}$.

Comment: Here's what I think they're going for.  What I'm missing here, however, is how exactly do they define the "natural linear map" $T'$?

Comment: T'(v)=T(v) +V_1

Comment: Ah, cool, then yes this was exactly the right trick